# JavaScript: функция передаётся по ссылке или по значению?

Tags: javascript

Нигде не нашел однозначного ответа на этот вопрос.

В коде ниже что будет находиться в copyFunc: ссылка, или объект функции?
Сколько экземпляров функции будет находиться в памяти после выполнения кода?

```
let myFunk = function () { /* func body */ };
let copyFunk = myFunk;
```

Comment: ссылка на эту же функцию

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По значению передаются только [примитивные типы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/Primitive). Т.е. `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `null`, `undefined` и `symbol`. Все остальные, в том числе `function`, передаются по ссылке.

Для не примитивных типов в переменных *всегда* хранятся ссылки на них. Часто для краткости говорят «в переменной лежит объект» когда имеют в виду, что в переменной лежит ссылка.

В вашем примере `myFunk` и `copyFunk` это две абсолютно одинаковых ссылки на *один* экземпляр функции.

Comment: Дополняя ответ: 1 экземпляр функции.